# Insert date time in google document

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, google-docs

I would like to insert a timestamp (date and/or time) into Google Documents. The support documentation () says that there should be a keyboard shortcut, but it does not work in my environment (Win7 + IE9).

Can anyone provide me with a Google Apps script to achieve this?

Comment: Apps Script can not add shortcuts or menus to a Google Document. What is it that need? I mean, the whole usage of this. Are you going to bulk appends timestamps to a bunch of documents? Or what else?

Comment: You're missing your link to the docs.  You may be looking at http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110, which is for Sheets, when you mean to be looking at the Docs help item http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179738&topic=1361462&ctx=topic, which has no such shortcut listed.

Comment: Nearly identical question on WebApps, asked 2 years before this one: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/can-i-print-the-print-date-or-save-date-in-google-documents

Answer (score 46):

This works well

In Google Docs : Tools -> Open Script Editor and save this script

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or FormApp or SpreadsheetApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertDate')
      .addToUi();

}

function insertDate() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
      // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
      // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
      var d = new Date();
      var dd = d.getDate();
      dd = pad(dd, 2)
      var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      mm = pad(mm, 2)
      var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
      var date = dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;
      var element = cursor.insertText(date);
      if (element) {
        element.setBold(true);
      } else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
      }
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }

}
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

Reload the Doc, Accept the permissions.

Comment: A quick ad hoc for those who want to use it in spreadsheets https://gist.github.com/mlatu/11498254

Comment: Is there a simple way to create a shortcut for this custom menu? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @KumarDeepak: I didn't try this yet but I would imagine you could update the onOpen to add a handler to check that all the keys of your hotkey are pressed.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me... If this is "solution", google has a LOOONG road ahead...

Comment: This is just working in the single document where I added the script,  but not on any other document! Meaning I'm getting the 'Utilities' option on a single document. I don't think this is the way it's supposed to work!

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if an add-on falls under the category Google Apps Script you were asking for, bug [Text Factory](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-factory/ppiaifpokkcagpcadampdmlpegldaaoc?utm_source=permalink) provides the feature to insert a time-stamp.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The Text Factory add-on requires excessive permissions within Google Apps. I will not be allowing this on my Google Apps account.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: As of Feb. 1st, 2022, Google Doc seems providing the date in its menu, invoked by inserting @ at the beginning of a line in a document.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an edited version (of the one already provided) that prints out a date stamp including the time.

Here is an example of the output: 2:43:21 AM EST 26-03-2014

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or FormApp or SpreadsheetApp.
  ui.createMenu('Insert Date')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertDate')
      .addToUi();

}

function insertTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();  // Number of ms since Jan 1, 1970

  // OR:

  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:35 PM", for instance
}

function insertDate() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
      // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
      // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
      var d = new Date();
      var dd = d.getDate();
      dd = pad(dd, 2)
      var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      mm = pad(mm, 2)
      var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
      var timeStamp = d.getTime();  // Number of ms since Jan 1, 1970
      var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:35 PM", for instance
      var date = currentTime + " " + dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;
      var element = cursor.insertText(date);
      if (element) {
        element.setBold(true);
      } else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
      }
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }

}
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get automatically **current date after open document**, you can add this script:

In Google Docs: **Tools -> Open Script Editor** and save this script:

```js
/** 
 *  After open document actualize part with text "Generated" to "Generated [actual date]".
 */

function onOpen() {  
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd.MM.yyyy");
  // Clear the text surrounding "Apps Script", with or without text.
  body.replaceText("^Generated.*$", "Generated " + date);    
}
```

**In the document body you must have text "Generated".**

Answer (score 5):

### Create a new Sheets document

In A1, put `Date:` and B1, put the formula `NOW()`. I named the sheet `current-date`, but you can name it whatever you want. This document will simply sit on your drive to server as a "date keeper" for all of your Docs documents.

[image: New Sheet NOW()]

### Format Cell as Date

Select cell B1 and choose `Number >> Date` from the `Format` menu.

[image: Format Date]

### Select Cells and Copy

Select cells A1 and B1, right click, and choose `Copy`

[image: Select and Copy]

### Paste and Link to Docs Document

Right click in your Docs document where you want to paste the cells and click `Paste`. Docs should ask you if you want to link these cells to the source document. Select `Link to spreadsheet` and then click `Paste`.

[image: Paste and Link]

### Get Rid of the Borders

To get rid of the borders, right click on the inserted cells and select `Table Properties`.

[image: Table Properties]

Now set `Table Border` to `0pt` and click `OK`.

[image: Border Zero]

### Final Result

You should end up with something like this. You can drag the edges of the cells to make them bigger or smaller and change the font and text size of the cells as well. If you make the text bigger, the text will wrap inside the cells so you will need to make them wider.

[image: Final Result]

### Updating the Date

Now whenever you open your document with the linked cells and the date has changed, you should see this. Click `Update` and your date will be updated to today's date. There is no need to ever open the `current-date` spreadsheet!

[image: Update Cells]

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

For Docs, you are probably out of luck, as there appears to be [no hotkey for that](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179738&topic=1361462&ctx=topic), and support for scripting from within Docs is lacking (Spreadsheets would be a different story).  Since you're on Windows, you can avail yourself of [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), though.  [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzNiR0t4VNk), while way too long, shows assigning a global hotkey combo to insert the current date anywhere.  With that, you can insert your date/time anywhere you want to while using your Windows system.  (You can customize it to be only active in certain applications, such as IE, if you want to get wacky with it)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, autohotkey is the way to go. Gotta love it. Thanks for the comment Brian!

Answer (score 3):

Because extra key-strokes are being used to insert the date from the menu, my solution is a batch file, sts.cmd, that stores the date-time into the clip-board when called, enabling an easy Windows+R, sts, Ctrl+V to get and paste. If you are adding extra keystrokes to get the date into the doc anyway you might as well just paste it in.
The code is

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=1-12 delims=/:. " %%d in ("%time%") do SET MYTIME= %%d:%%e:%%f
for /f "tokens=1-12 delims=/:. " %%d in ("%date%") do SET MYDATE= %%g-%%e-%%f
SET MYTS=%MYDATE%%MYTIME%
ECHO | SET /p dummyname=%MYTS%|clip
```

This works for me until GDocs comes up with an embeddable function that will update the display date to the current date each time the doc is opened.

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS, I used Automator.

I created a Service that works with Chrome, takes no input, and runs a shell script and sends the output to the clipboard. The shell script is very basic:

```
DateTime=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`
echo $DateTime
```

I could have done without the intermediate variable and just run the date command, but I had the idea that I might want to do extra processing and formatting. Note that if you want to include spaces in your formatting of the date string, the formatting argument must be in quotes. The screen shot uses an underbar instead.

[image]
With the script saved, I went to System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts, I found my script DateTime2CB.workflow in the Text section and gave it a hotkey. There's no easy way of finding out what hotkeys are in use.

I could have made it for any app (and if I find myself trying to use it other apps I still might do that), but for now it's Chrome only. I could also have had the shell script pipe the output of date to the clipboard, pbcopy on Mac, as above (using "clip"). I've tested both methods and they work.

I added the same script to another Mac and it was set up to insist that the Automator file (*name*.workflow) be saved in iCloud. in that context, it was not listed in the Keyboard settings. To fix that, I had to reopen the saved iCloud file in Automator using Open > Recent. It asked if I wanted to install the file in Services. A yes answer at that point saved it on my local system and I could find it under Settings > Keyboard > Shorcuts > Services.

I hope this helps other Mac users.

August

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!! 

Is it possible to make it paste directly? Ideally I would want to press just one keyboard shortcut combination in order to get the datetime (when I'm in a text editor).

Comment: Btw, I set it up a bit differently (because the workflow didn't appear in System Settings even after trying your fix), using the Shortcuts app. Once I had the .workflow file, I dragged it into the Shortcuts app, and then in the ⓘ tab added a keyboard shortcut ("Run with"). It didn't work at first because the shortcut I originally tried was already taken (I think).

Comment: Since the above was written, I have changed to using Keyboard Maestro macro. I have macros that insert the date and weekday and the full date and time. They are accessible either by hotkey or by text replacement. E.g., when I type "=dd=" it gets automatically replaced by the date and weekday. When I type "=tt=" I get the numerical date and time string.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```js
function insertTimestamp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();

  cell.setValue(new Date());
  // sets the cells format to month/day/year.
  // Remove if you want time inserted as well
  cell.setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy") 
}
```

This works on spreadsheets not sure if you were looking for other docs.

Comment: Doesn't apply to Docs (as OP asked for), hence downvote.

Answer (score -4):

Create a Spreadsheet Today in google docs.  Put the date in B1 as Today() Format it in C1 using the function Text(B1,"dddd, mmmm d, yyyy")
Then use the following script (you will need the url of the Today Spreadsheet

```js
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body1 = doc.getBody();
  var style1 = {};
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var text1 = doc.editAsText();
  body1.appendHorizontalRule(); 
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('spreadsheet url');
  var ss = wb.getSheetByName('Today');
  var r = ss.getRange('C1');
  var date1 = r.getValues();
  var par1 =body1.appendParagraph(date1[0]);
  par1.setAttributes(style1);
}
```

Comment: Where can I apply the function in a Doc?

Comment: Doesn't apply to Docs (as OP asked for), hence downvote.